# How to deploy next js / node application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, mern

I'm working on a full-stack project where for front-end I use next.js application while for api I use node / express server. frontend and backend operate on different ports. My application is configured as in the picture:
[image]

I'm new to next js and this would be of great benefit to me

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy on Heroku

Step 1: Login on [heroku.com](https://id.heroku.com/login)

Step 2: Create an app on Heroku

Step 3: Install Heroku CLI

Step 4: Create a file name `Procfile` and write

```
web: node your-server-index-file.js
```

Step 5: Follow the instruction of Heroku to deploy an app

Comment: Thank you. I can deploy both frontend and backend on heroku, sure?

Comment: Yea you can do that

Comment: Okay I'll try if it works for me

Comment: what should I add in Procfile in frontend folder?

Comment: No, add it to the parent folder of frontend and backend folder
and create a repository there

Comment: Okay, which file should it point? Do you mean server.js from backend?

Comment: Yep, sorry for replying u late